# geoserver-rest _ ERROR: ... install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: gdal, pip

I'm trying to install geoserver-rest from cmd with pip, following the instructions in documentation
(https://geoserver-rest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin refresh
pipwin install gdal
```

### (without pipwin pycurl is deprecated)

|  | versions | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GeoServer | 2.24.1 | in Program Files |
| Java | jdk-17.0.9+9-jre | in Program Files |
| GeoServer | 2.24.1 | in Program Files |
| Python | 3.12.0 | in Program Files |

---

I created a virtual environment in a "geoserver_rest" folder with cmd:

```
cd Desktop
cd geoserver_rest
python -m virtualenv .\venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install pipwin
pipwin refresh
pipwin install gdal
pip install geoserver-rest
```

### note: runned pipwin install gdal in cmd a final output is KeyError:3

Unfortunately, when I start the pip install geoserver-rest command, these errors appear in cmd:
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
Failed to build gdal
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gdal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[image]

Anyone have any ideas?
tnk!
ps_ I leave some potentially useful links:
https://youtu.be/9Yah7YHi9qc?si=URGMGli9Nu1PQIRE
https://gdal.org/

Comment: Please paste the error message as text rather screenshots.

Comment: did you try following the instructions in the error message?